# TkZ-Euclide: dim parameter results in an error while in tabular environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tabularx, tkz-euclide

I am attempting to draw the dimension of a line segment for my tkz-euclide drawing while in tabular environment. For some reason this results in an error. It should be noted, that I do not have any problems with including tkz-euclide drawings in tabular environment. The error arises only when the dim parameter is used.

Here is a minimal example that results in an error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
            \tkzDefPoint(5,0){B}
            \tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
            % Excluding the following line removes the error
            \tkzDrawSegment[dim={$5\mathrm m$, 12pt,}](A,B)
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However, the same tikz drawing works while outside of the tabular environment. For example, the following code works without any issues:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
        \tkzDefPoint(5,0){B}
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
        \tkzDrawSegment[dim={$5\mathrm m$, 12pt,}](A,B)
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Apart from the tabular environment I have also tried tabu and tabularx – the error still persists.

What could have caused this error, and how I could circumnavigate it? Ideally, I would like to continue working with tkz-euclide rather than defining my own 'dim' equivalent, but any solution is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: don't use the tabu package. It is broken and unmaintained.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, I will try to look for alternatives! However, the issue still persists when using tabular or tabularx instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What could have caused this error?* Well, some interference of `tkz-euclide` with `tabular`, probably not worth to investigate (except if you are the maintainer of `tkz-euclide`).

*How to circumvent the problem?* I found that in most cases of such interferences, the following method works:

1. Define a `\newsavebox`, e.g. `\newsavebox\mydrawing`
2. Use `\savebox` to typeset the contents interfering with the outer environment into this box, e.g.,

   ```
   \savebox\mydrawing{\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}}
   ```
3. Use the box instead of the original contents, e.g., `\usebox\mydrawing`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\newsavebox\mydrawing
\savebox\mydrawing{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(5,0){B}
  \tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
  \tkzDrawSegment[dim={$5\mathrm m$, 12pt,}](A,B)
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
before
\begin{tabular}{c}
  above\\
  \usebox\mydrawing\\
  below
\end{tabular}
after
\end{document}
```

Comment: Genius! Thanks for that,very clever solution. I think, anyway, that Alain Matthes should take a look at this weird interference.